# How to Trigger jQuery event on item in set (unexpected jQuery results from $._data() with first element of set)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to automate the clicking of the header of a table column so that a table sorts automatically on page load.  (The table is injected by a Confluence plugin, so we can't control its content, sorting, or CSS easily.)

Each `<th>` in the table has `class="sortableHeader"`.  Using jQuery to get the set of header items:

```
$('th.sortableHeader')
```

Returns the expected array of jQuery objects, and getting the events associated with the first item in the array works just fine if I do it this way:

```
$._data( $('th.sortableHeader')[0], "events")
```

*Object {mousedown: Array[1], mouseup: Array[1]}
mousedown: Array[1]
mouseup: Array[1]
**proto**: Object*

Of course I can't call `.trigger()` on that guy, because he's not a jQuery object.  So I tried to get the same object (I thought) using `.first()` or `.slice(0,1)`, but that's where things get weird:

```
$._data( $('th.sortableHeader').first(), "events")
```

*undefined*

```
$._data( $('th.sortableHeader').slice(0,1), "events")
```

*undefined*

I would have expected the bottom two to produce the same results as the first.  Can someone explain why the events don't show up?  (Obviously, if the events don't show up, then I can't `.trigger()` them!)

Comment: `$._data(` wants a dom node. therefore `.first` and `.slice` won't work. Your first attempt that worked is what you need. What does `.trigger` have to do with this? getting the event from $._data is irrelevant when it comes to triggering events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// trigger mouseup on all matching elements
$('th.sortableHeader').trigger('mouseup');

// trigger mouseup on first matching element
$('th.sortableHeader').first().trigger('mouseup');
```

To find the events (and handlers), you already solved:

```
$._data( $('th.sortableHeader')[0], "events");
```

This returns the event objects saved in jQuery, but you don’t "need" them to trigger them, jQuery abstracts that part in `.trigger()`.

If you want to be really troublesome, try something like:

```
var ev = $._data( $('th.sortableHeader')[0], "events");
// ev is now an object of events
ev.mouseup.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.handler();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YECr5/

Answer (score 1):

Why not wait for your plugin to finish loading then just trigger which ever event you want on whichever element you want?

This selects all th elements with the sortableHeader class, then filters out all but the first element.  This returns a jQuery object.

```
$('th.sortableHeader').first().trigger('click');
```

or

This does the same but returns a DOM object, so to make it a jquery object you can wrap it in jQuery selector.

```
var mySelection = $('th.sortableHeader')[0];
$(mySelection).trigger('click');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/colbycallahan/uJusL/

Comment: I did try both of those.  The second one errors because [0] is a DOM object, not a jQuery object, so you get "TypeError: [0].trigger is not a function".  The first one just doesn't seem to work, and I believe that's because if you ask jQuery what the events of `.first()` are, you get `undefined` (see my OP).